# create an array from a text file or another array that is based on tabbed spaces?

Tags: php

What I am ultimately trying to do is take a text file that looks like below and organize them into something I can use like an array based on tabbed spaces.

// Example //

```
this is no tabbed space
     this is a tabbed space
          this is 2 tabbed spaces
this is no tabbed space
```

I would like to end up with:(using PHP preferably)

```
$list= array(no \t("string", "string", "string", one \t ("string", "string", "string", 
tw0 \t("string", "string", "string", etc..)),

no \t again starts new("string", "string", array());
```

I need to keep nesting based on \t spaces and start over when I hit no \t space.
Any suggestions or better ways to do this?

I need to use this list from a text file to insert into database as categories and use for menu items that have sub levels and as many needed depending on the text file.

I figured out how to get them into one array but is there a way to organize them by the tabbed spaces or maybe by if greater than a certain amount of spaces etc..? I am just confused at this piont been trying many different ways but I am truly lost.

Comment: Your task might be easier if you use XML.

Comment: Would there be a way to wrap text in a text file with XML?

Comment: Take a look at YAML, it has an indentation-based structure. Also, there are YAML parsers for PHP.

Comment: I agree with @AlienWebguy. With xml also use [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) for reading from the xml files.

Comment: Thanks will check it out now!

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the comments to your question, you should rethink the data format if it is at all an option. If it is not, however, you could use something to this effect to solve the problem:

```
$list = array ();
foreach ($lines as $line)
{
    $depth = NULL;
    $string = preg_replace ('/\t/', '', $line, -1, &$depth);
    isset ($list[$depth]) ? array_push ($list[$depth], $string) : $list[$depth] = array ($string, );
}
```

`$lines` is assumed to be an array with the lines of the text file, something like `file(textfile)` or `explode("\n", file_get_contents(textfile))`. Using `preg_replace()` we trim the tabs from each `$line` and get the `$depth` from the number of times `\t` is replaced with nothing. Ultimately the trimmed string is appended to an array, `$list[$depth]` -- but if it is not initialized to an array, we do that and add `$string` as the first element.

It is assumed that there are no other tabs in the string, if this could be the case you'd need to go for a more verbose solution, perhaps something like this, within the `foreach()` loop:

```
$depth = 0;
$string = $line;
while (preg_match ('/^\t/', $string))
{
        $string = preg_replace ('/^\t/', '', $string);
        $depth ++;
}

isset ($output[$depth]) ? array_push ($output[$depth], $string) : $output[$depth] = array ($string, );
```

Neither of these solutions might qualify if execution time is essential, but they're simple to implement.

Also note, the array will come out as an associative array of arrays with a numeric index, this will not be ordered, so you might need to use `asort()` if you needed it ordered.

Comment: I have tried to use these ideas and was unable to get them to work. It would just stop at the first tab and display everything else under that level of the array.

Comment: @JohnMeher : The solution assumes proper tabs, is this the case, or are there lines with say four or eight whitespace characters? In that case, change the `\t` part in the regular expressions with `(\t| {4})` or `(\t| {8})` accordingly. If this does not apply, could you post part of the data somewhere, where tabs are not converted to whitespace?

Comment: Let me retry and I will post everything I come up with here.

Comment: I know it has been awhile but every now and then I play with this and still cannot get my head around it. Though I have been able to get the count of tab spaces for each line. What I cannot get my head around is how to filter or dynamically build an array of array's from a single array based on a condition. Always end up having trouble with the nested foreach and whiles loops etc.. Loop are not my cup of tea when it comes to recursion.